# List append resets list in recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

I am running the following code to attempt a simulation of Hanoi recursively but on running the code the list `[[1,3]]` is returned every time as `hlist` is reset in the loop. How can I rectify this?

```
def playHanoi(p1,p2,p3,n):
    hlist=[]
    if n==1:
        hlist.append([p1,p3])
    else:
        playHanoi(p1,p3,p2,n-1)
        hlist.append([p1,p3])
        playHanoi(p2,p1,p3,n-1)
    return(hlist)
```

Comment: You could try making hlist an argument of `playHanoi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `global` is one way to do that:

```
hlist = []

def playHanoi(p1,p2,p3,n):
    global hlist
    if n==1:
        hlist.append([p1,p3])
    else:
        playHanoi(p1,p3,p2,n-1)
        hlist.append([p1,p3])
        playHanoi(p2,p1,p3,n-1)
    return(hlist)
```

a second (and probably cleaner) way is to use `hlist` as function argument:

```
def playHanoi(p1,p2,p3,n, hlist=None):

    if hlist is None:
        hlist = []

    if n==1:
        hlist.append([p1,p3])
    else:
        playHanoi(p1,p3,p2,n-1, hlist)
        hlist.append([p1,p3])
        playHanoi(p2,p1,p3,n-1, hlist)
    return(hlist)
```

Comment: I would choose the second option

Comment: You actually never want to use mutable objects as default arguments. This is quite a common mistake in python. The following link explains: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Comment: @MrName well i did it on purpose here... but i agree. fixed.

Comment: @MrName no, you can use mutable default arguments, you just have to understand the semantics.

Answer (score 0):

hlist is only defined in the function. If you define hlist=[] first, every use of hlist.append([tobeappended]) is appended to the (global) list.